# Grep multiple and find multiple patterns

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have logs in below format, I am trying to grep multiple fields from them.

```
2020-09-23 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-428] localhost.com CLIENT_ID=abc CLIENT_IP=1.2.3 CLASS_NAME=ABCIMPL METHOD_NAME=789{Roles} REQUEST=[<Request>
some text
</Request>
2020-09-23 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-428] localhost.com CLIENT_ID=mno CLIENT_IP=1.2.4 CLASS_NAME=MNOP METHOD_NAME=1234{Decisions} REQUEST=[<Request>
some text
</Request>
```

I want to capture 3 fields in a text file in below format.

```
CLIENT_ID=abc , CLASS_NAME=ABCIMPL , METHOD_NAME=789{Roles}
CLIENT_ID=mno ,  CLASS_NAME=MNOP ,  METHOD_NAME=1234{Decisions}
```

I am able to capture one field but not all of them.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried using awk  .. something like awk -F[ CLIENT_ID ] '{print $2}' but it doesnt work

Comment: @user2854333, kindly do always add your efforts in your question, not in comments please.

Comment: `-F'[ CLIENT_ID ]'` is equivalent to `-F'[ CLIENT_D]'` or `-F' |C|L|I|E|N|T|_|D'`, i.e. it's specifying a set of characters to use as the FS, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" , "
}
match($0,/CLIENT_ID[^ ]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/CLASS_NAME[^ ]*/)
  val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/METHOD_NAME[^ ]*/)
  print val,val1,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  val=val1=""
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed` to capture the fields of interest:

```
sed  -nE 's/.* (CLIENT_ID=[^[:space:]]*).* (CLASS_NAME=[^[:space:]]*).* (METHOD_NAME=[^[:space:]]*).*/\1, \2, \3/p' file
CLIENT_ID=abc, CLASS_NAME=ABCIMPL, METHOD_NAME=789{Roles}
CLIENT_ID=mno, CLASS_NAME=MNOP, METHOD_NAME=1234{Decisions}
```

Comment: `[^[:space:]]` in GNU sed can be replaced by `\S`.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is log file, your field positions are fixed. You can use this simple awk:

```
awk -v OFS=' , ' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}$/{ print $5, $6, $8}' file.log
```

```
CLIENT_ID=abc , CLIENT_IP=1.2.3 , METHOD_NAME=789{Roles}
CLIENT_ID=mno , CLIENT_IP=1.2.4 , METHOD_NAME=1234{Decisions}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk script. You can define any patterns for printing and their separator. Also I match a date at the beginning of lines in interest, you could also modify that to your requirements if it is not enough.

```
BEGIN { p["CLIENT_ID="]; p["CLASS_NAME="]; p["METHOD_NAME="] }
 
 /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ {
    r = ""
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) for (x in p) if ($i ~ x) r = r? r ", " $i: $i
    print r
}
```

Usage:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file
CLIENT_ID=abc, CLASS_NAME=ABCIMPL, METHOD_NAME=789{Roles}
CLIENT_ID=mno, CLASS_NAME=MNOP, METHOD_NAME=1234{Decisions}
```