# grep out 2 field only

Tags: bash, grep

input text:

```
hello 34 others 28
```

I would like to run grep and get output the matched fields only:

```
34 28
```

I try below command but not as expected:

```
echo "hello 34 others 28" |grep -Eo "([0-9]+).*([0-9]+)"
```

Comment: Use `awk` instead of `grep`.

Comment: `grep` doesn't use capture groups. The `-o` option prints the entire matched string, so it includes the `.*` between the two numbers.

Comment: `awk '{print $2, $4}'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grep multiple and find multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029207/grep-multiple-and-find-multiple-patterns) (I use `sed`.)

Comment: Really, grep is the wrong tool for the job in the first place here. I second the awk suggestion -- there is literally nothing you can do with grep you can't also do with awk; it's 100% a superset.

Comment: (...and generally, _grumph_ about people asking "How do I use [wrong tool] to accomplish [job]?" instead of asking "How best can I accomplish [job]?" and leaving it to the experts they're asking to suggest the best tool for the purpose).

Comment: What is the general format for the input string? You posted only an **example**, which is not a specification. For your concrete example, `echo ... | |tr -d '[a-z]'` would do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe the following:

```bash
echo "hello 34 others 28" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tr '\n' ' '
```

The matching numbers are then translated from new-line delimited values to a space separated result.

Returns: `34 28`

You can add a positive lookbehind to tighten the matching criteria. You will have to use `Perl` mode instead of `Extended` mode. The lookbehind needs to be a fixed-width, so only a word character—follow by a space—is checked.

```bash
echo "hello 34 others 28" | grep -Po '(?<=\w )[0-9]+' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Or just `echo "hello 34 others 28" | sed -E 's/[^[:digit:]]+/ /g'` or maybe `echo $( grep -Eo '[0-9]+' <<< "hello 34 others 28" )`

Comment: Note that `grep -P` is very vendor-specific; even GNU grep doesn't always support it, since it depends on whether libpcre was compiled in. [Also, using libpcre makes your regex matching (potentially) very slow.](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)